# Include primary group in AD search with DirectorySearcher

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

I need to get a list of all users and contacts in a specific Active Directory group in my C# application. Which group is used is variable and changed with a configuration file.

Since System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement cannot handle contacts, I use DirectoryServices API with LDAP queries.

I use the following filter for my DirectorySearcher:

```
"(&(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=" + groupDN +")(objectClass=person))"
```

groupDN is the Distinguished Name of the source group.

This works fine for normal groups, but it should be possible to have the configured group as any group, even "Domain Users". Since our Domain Users group doesn't actually have members, but is used as a primary group, the above filter returns 0 results when the group is "Domain Users".

I know that you can search for primary group membership with the filter:

```
(primaryGroupId=513)
```

but that doesn't account for other groups similar to Domain Users ("primary groups" if you will).

Is there another way to include primary group members in the search results?

Answer (score 1):

The primaryGroupId attribute contains last part of group SID (objectSid attribute). The following MS article describes technique used to get primary group of a security principal: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/297951/how-to-use-the-primarygroupid-attribute-to-find-the-primary-group-for

Be aware that chain filter, which is used to retrieve membership returns you users from nested groups, but has performance issues on domain containing 10K+ users

Comment: I used a filter like `(&(|(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=[groupDN])(primaryGroupId=[groupRID]))(objectClass=person))` and extracted the RID from the SID of the group. That works if the source group is directly "Domain Users" or any non-primary group. It doesn't work if "Domain Users" is a subgroup of the source group. Do you know any way to handle a case like this?

Comment: Ok, so now I see. You are looking for nested groups and users these groups are set as primary. I solved this issue with recursive ad query. From my experience it's much more efficient to make recursive paginated query then use chain filter. A good example of such query can be found in .net developers guide for directory services programming book. This is a must have book if you work with active directory and c#